# Docker container with redis runned as daemon doesn't run

Tags: node.js, docker, redis

I have simple Dockerfile

```
FROM base

RUN <code which installs redis>
RUN npm install redis-adapter

EXPOSE 6379

ENTRYPOINT redis-server --daemonize yes && /app/tasks/redis/entrypoint.sh
```

And in my entrypoint I'm setting up some configurational keys and set some data to redis via node:

```
#!/bin/sh

redis-cli hset app:cfg env dev
redis-cli hset app:cfg maxconnections 1024

node /app/tasks/redis/init.js
```

Image builds succesfully, but when I running it - nothing happens. What's the problem? What should I do to run redis in container and make some configuration after? May be the trouble is in that I'm running redis as daemon?

Comment: Could you write your error message, please?

Comment: @AlexGalera There is no error message. On `docker run <image_id>` I receive messages from my node script that configuration was successfull and it's all. 

Looks like: 


$ docker run a7deb97f2cb5
node_redis: Warning: Redis server does not require a password, but a password was supplied.
Reply: OK, app-configs setup
Reply: OK, app-runtime setup
Reply: OK, cfg setup

Comment: Could you post `docker logs <container>` output, please?

Comment: Same as text above. Success messages from node script and it's all.

Comment: Does it works if you execute the same steps outside container?

Comment: Yes, it runs redis-server on default port 6379, after starts my node script which configures keys. But redis-server was running as daemon, so when I execute that outside container I'm also get ok message from script and then can connect to redis via `redis-cli` or something. I'm wondering why container doesn't runs. What should do `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`? If it returns `0` does container starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answer from author*

**TL:DR**

There is a pretty similiar question in Stackoverflow which help to fix my problem:

- [Running redis on nodejs Docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966097/running-redis-on-nodejs-docker-image?rq=1)

The problem was in that a Docker `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` should "spawn single process". And I put Redis starting and node `init.js` execution as different programs into `supervisord`. Providing `supervisord.conf` for example:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
loglevel=debug

[program:redis]
priority=1
command=redis-server

[program:configurations]
priority=2
command=/bin/sh -c /app/tasks/redis/entrypoint.sh
```

**Why did I do that?**

The main trouble which I have with this issue was with misunderstanding what actually is a Docker container. And what does `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` in Docker. I thought that I should just *"run some server into Docker and expose some port and Docker will do everything with itself"*, but that is not the way how containers work. There is a difference between containers and VM's. Look this: [How is Docker different from a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047306/how-is-docker-different-from-a-virtual-machine?rq=1)

When thinking about Docker container as a wrap over one single process it seems clear that code written in my `Dockerfile` will not work in way that I was expected.

If there is a need to run multiple processes in Docker container then you should use something like `supervisord` or `concurrently` (if you prefer `Node` ecosystem).