# Can't connect Redis server to nodejs, Docker compose

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, redis

I'm struggling to connect a redis deployment to my nodejs app. Of course locally without the use of docker, it works well, so I'm at odds as to whether this is an issue to do with my code, or the way I've set up my docker compose file

Dockerfile:

```js
FROM node:8
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-compose.yml

```js
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    container_name: web-container
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - redis
    build: . 
    ports: 
    - "3000:3000"
    links: 
      - redis
  redis:
    container_name: redis-container
    image: "redis:latest"
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

Redis Connection File (RedisService.js)

```js
const redis         = require("redis");
const client        = redis.createClient();
const DbUtils       = require("../../db_utils");
const {promisify}   = require("util");
const getAsync      = promisify(client.get).bind(client);
const existsAsync   = promisify(client.exists).bind(client);

class RedisCache {
    constructor () {
        var connected;
        // * Initiliase the connection to redis server
        client.on("connect", () => {console.log(" Redis cache is ready"); connected = true;})
        client.on("error", (e) => {console.log("Redis cache error:\n" + e); connected = false;});
    }

    async setData (id, data) {
        // * Stringify data if it's an object
        data = data instanceof Object ? JSON.stringify(data) : data;
        client.set(id, data);
        return true;
    }

    async getData (key) {
        return getAsync(key).then(data => {
            data = JSON.parse(data) instanceof Object ? JSON.parse(data) : data;
            return data; 
        })
    }

    async exists (key) {
        return existsAsync(key).then(bool => {
            return bool;
        })
    }

    // Returns status of redis cache
    async getStatus () {
        return this.connected;
    }
}

module.exports = new RedisCache();
```

**ERROR**
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.11:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.11:6379

Comment: you should use `redis` as host in this case when connecting to redis container from nodejs container.

Comment: so: redis.createClient({host: "redis"})

?

Comment: I am not well familiar with docker compose. if running redis on the same container as your nodejs app is something that helps you, then go through this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966097/running-redis-on-nodejs-docker-image

Comment: Will give this a shot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run your containers via `docker-compose` they are all connected to a common network. Service name is a DNS name of given container so to access `redis` container from `web` you should create the client like :

```
const client = redis.createClient({
        port      : 6379,
        host      : 'redis'
});
```

You have not configured the host so it uses the default one - `127.0.0.1`. But from the point of view of your `web` container the redis is not running on the localhost. Instead it runs in it's own container which DNS name is `redis`.

Comment: Ahh I see okay, let me give that a try. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Yep that did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The beginning (docker part) of this tutorial worked for me :
https://medium.com/geekculture/using-redis-with-docker-and-nodejs-express-71dccd495fd3

```
docker run -d --name <CONTAINER_NAME> -p 127.0.0.1:6379:6379 redis
```

then in the node server (like in official redis website example) :

```
const redis = require('redis');

async function start() {
    const client = redis.createClient(6379,'127.0.0.1');
    await client.connect();

    await client.set('mykey', 'Hello from node redis');
    const myKeyValue = await client.get('mykey');
    console.log(myKeyValue); 
}

start();
```

Comment: not connecting with redis 
    at async start (...\backend\app.js:14:3) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 6379
}